# .htaccess для локальных адресов

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, symfony

Изучаю symfony и столкнулся с неприятной вещью, я вынужден маршруты настраивать следующим образом `mysite/user` и `url` будет такой `localhost/mysite/user`, как правильно настроить `.htaccess` что бы в маршрутах я писал `/user`. Хочу это сделать, что бы в будущем безболезненно перейти на прод хост. Вот так сейчас выглядит мой `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ibb/public/index.php [L]
```

P.S. Что почитать, что бы самому научиться писать для него правила?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть документацию https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html